# Checking if a table is present in database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a list called `tList`, which contains names of `tables` of a `database`. Tables in this list may or may not exist. I want to retrieve data from every table if it is present. I am doing it like this.

```
for(String t:tList){
    sql=Select * from t
}
```

But in this scenario if `table` is not present, I am getting exception that table is not present and my program gets terminate. How to handle this so that I can retrieve data only and only if that table is present

In one more scenario if table is present but it is empty than also I am getting error. Please help in these two scenarios

Comment: Well, ... you can catch the exception .... And an empty table should not give you an error.

Comment: Is it oracle? Or what databse?

Comment: sybase database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [DatabaseMetaData.getTables()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) 
 Example:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, t, null); //t is your tableName (defined in loop of your question)
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

> Edit

To answer your empty table question:

```
  //your query
  sql=Select * from t
  Statement  stmt = yourDBConnection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  if (!rs .isBeforeFirst() ) {    
   System.out.println("Table is empty"); 
  }
```

Comment: tried but  I think this is for getting all tables from database and I think in this also I will get same problem

Comment: I will try it once again but along with it I want to check if table is empty or not. If it is empty I want my program to run. Can I handle this with the above statement

Comment: Table empty is different from your question `I want to retrieve data from every table if it is present.`

Empty table will result you empty result set, and .next() will be false.

Comment: I am pretty sure if table will be empty it will give exception

Comment: Try it out to validate :)

Comment: Could you please show me how to validate.. It will help me to understand your point

Comment: Surprised. You said it will throw exception. You could have executed command select * from <table> where table is empty and seen it. Anyway, I updated the answer for your requirement too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the more appropriate way is to get data is java.sql.DataBaseMetaData.

A java.sql.Connection object is able to provide information describing its tables, its supported SQL grammar, its stored procedures, the capabilities of this connection, and so on. This information is obtained with the getMetaData method.

Refer:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html